Adding a capacitor to the output of an op-amp can cause instability? (PCB trace capacitance)
In my amplifier design, I checked all the possible issue for finding the instability problem in my previous post: Transimpedance amplifier with OPA838 - oscillation - supply voltage , Transimpedance amplifier with OPA838 - instability. I noticed the PCB trace that is connected to the output of my amplifier has capacitance of 171pF per meter length( a better scale might be 0.171pF/mm). For 120 mm would be around 18pF.:

By this trace the output is connected to the a connector. Can this capacitance on the output cause an instability? If yes, how can I fix it on the PCB? or how to quickly do a test to verify that the issue is there?

Your trace is 1m long?

@Tim Williams mt trace length is about120 mm long

That says 170 pF per meter. If your trace is less than a meter, it will have proportionally lower capacitance.

@ Hearth Yes, or we can say  0.171pF/mm, that for 120 mm would be around 18pF.


I noticed the PCB trace that is connected to the output of my
amplifier has capacitance of 170pF

This is what TI recommend for their OPA838 op-amp regarding capacitive loads: -


Thank you Andy, very useful information, there is18pF capacitance now on the output of OPA838 because of the PCB trace, which should cause stability issue, I will check- the performance with a series resistor and let you know the results.

Bear in mind that you must the add the resistor irrespective of what the result is. You have no choice even if things don’t appear to improve. The same with any other recommendation in the data sheet. If you don’t do something that is recommended, you may never solve the problem @Behnam

Your calculator shows 171pF per meter length.  It seems unlikely that your transmission line stretches anywhere a meter; a better scale might be 0.171pF/mm.
That said, capacitance can affect an op-amp's stability.  The effect is dependent on the characteristics such as drive current and gain/bandwidth product of the op amp, as well as the surrounding circuitry.  In general, less than 50pF won't be an issue unless your circuit has a lot of gain at higher frequencies.  However, it's worth remaining aware of the possibility, as it can vary considerably.

Thank you for the answer, The length of my track is 110 mm, so it would be around 18pF, I did a quick simulation and it seems even with 20pF it is still stable, do you have any idea what could be reason for instability of that circuit?

I'd take a look at the input circuit.  At 60KHz, that 10nF cap is about 250 ohms reactive, forming a corner with R1.  It seems that R2 is converting  your sensor current to a voltage, and the C5/R1 feedback is attempting to create a differentiator.  With a differentiator, though, the gain gets arbitrarily large with frequency.  A bit of series R with C5 (say 250 ohms or thereabouts) might level it out...if you intended to make a differentiator to start with.  You also have a direct capacitive feedback path (C1-C5) to your sensor, which may interact with it based on the sensor characteristics..

If it goes to a connector, what's the capacitance of the cable it connects to?
When driving a cable with a fast opamp, it is good practice to put a ~50Ω resistor between the opamp and the cable.
Edit:
Figure 7-49 on the OPA838 data sheet suggests that it's quite touchy about capacitive loading. As far as the output stage is concerned, your capacitive feedback is a load, as well. But you can't decouple the feedback cap with a resistor, that would surely destabilize. So, try a resistor in series with the output trace, close to the opamp. That should help. If you can live with the bandwidth reduction, added capacitance between the output trace and ground, after the added resistor, may also help (without the added resistor, it will most likely make the problem worse).
This is not an area where simulation is entirely reliable. It may be that you simply can't use the OPA838 in this kind of circuit.

it is an normal connector connector very similar to a FMC connector, so it do not have any idea about the capacitance of it,  the length of the track on my PCB, is 110 mm to the  connector.

@Behnam The total capacitance of everything attached to the output is what matters, trace, connector, and everything the connector attaches to. Scope probe, too, if you're looking at it with a scope. Best to put a resistor at the opamp output.

thanks, I will check.  One side of the resistor should be connected to the opamp output and the other side to GND?

@Behnam No, in series.

@ John Doty thank you for the nice guidance, what value should I choose for the series resistor?

@Behnam You have to guess: your application is sufficiently different from anythin on the datasheet that it's hard to say. I'd try 50Ω or so.

An important insight, for high frequency operation, is that traces are transmission lines.
Which is the origin of the calculations shown, and the importance of the other parameters shown there.
At low frequencies, below cutoff, transmission lines can be approximated as series inductance and shunt capacitance.  Primarily one or the other, depending on whether circuit / system impedance is below or above Zo, respectively.  Cutoff is given by electrical length.  Velocity is 146 m/µs, so 110mm is 0.75ns electrical length, the corresponding 1/4λ cutoff frequency being 330MHz.
A resistor in series with a transmission line, turns it into a source-terminated line, with a resistive characteristic at high frequencies, transitioning to a lossy C characteristic at low frequencies.  This might still be problematic for an op-amp, but it gives a much better chance of success in any case.
Curiously, the datasheet only provides simulated data, and only to 10MHz, for output impedance (Fig.7-38, p.15).  With these data extended out to or beyond cutoff, we could at least guess whether it might go unstable -- stability is more than just an impedance plot, but any sudden changes in impedance, or if the impedance is above or below R or Zo, would be useful background information.  Unfortunately, data up to 10MHz basically just tells us what we already know, it's normal closed-loop passband behavior.
If a design solution is not possible, it can at least be tested.  I would recommend testing output impedance or step response, and adjust the series resistance to peak the frequency response as desired.
You also haven't mentioned what's at the end of the trace, or connector if applicable.  Needless to say, a cable extends the transmission line further, and termination will be required.  Termination can be placed at either end of the line, or even both ends (generally improves flatness, at expense of 6dB gain).
Note that an end-terminated transmission line looks like a constant resistance, ensuring no instability for anything that can drive such a load nominally.

Finally I could verify this by several measurements and experiments. So, based on the  PCB trace calculator, there was 18pF capacitance on the output pin of OPA838. Based on the datasheet this chip can not handle more than 6 pF capacitance on the output. So, by disconnecting the output track, in fact I removed the capacitance on the output and the circuit works well (we do not see instability and high current draw from the system). The root cause for this issue was the capacitance on the output.

